# How to send big txt file approximately 10 gb from server to client in windows form?

Tags: c#

I am trying to send file from client to file but it cannot handle big txt file.

This my client side of uploading file:

```
private void uploadFile(string fileName)
        {
            string filePath = "";
            /* File reading operation. */
            Console.WriteLine(fileName);
            fileName = fileName.Replace("\\", "/");
            while (fileName.IndexOf("/") > -1)
            {
                filePath += fileName.Substring(0, fileName.IndexOf("/") + 1);
                fileName = fileName.Substring(fileName.IndexOf("/") + 1);
            }
            byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileName);
      
           //TODO
            byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath + fileName);
            /* Read & store file byte data in byte array. */
            byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileData.Length];
            /* clientData will store complete bytes which will store file name length, 
            file name & file data. */
            byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length);
            /* File name length’s binary data. */
            fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
            fileNameByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
            fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length);
            /* copy these bytes to a variable with format line [file name length]
            [file name] [ file content] */

 
             clientSocket.Send(clientData);
        }
```

And this is the server side:

```
                byte[] clientData = new byte[1024 * 5000];
                int receivedBytesLen = client.Receive(clientData);
                int fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(clientData, 0);
                int dummy = Program.GetFilesByOwner(username).Count();
                
                string fileName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientData, 4, fileNameLen);
                string complete_name = "";
                Console.WriteLine("dummy");
                if (dummy == 0)
                {
                    complete_name = username + fileName;

                }
                else
                {
                     complete_name = username + fileName + "-" + "0" + $"{dummy}";          
                }
                /* Read file name */
                BinaryWriter bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(fileDirectory + "/" + (complete_name), FileMode.Append)); ;
               
                bWrite.Write(clientData, 4 + fileNameLen, receivedBytesLen - 4 - fileNameLen);
               
                bWrite.Close();
                
               
                Program.InsertFile(complete_name,fileDirectory,username,0);
```

It can send 2 gb file but above 2 gb it cannot send.Can you give me a solution?

Comment: To mention a few problems: why do you have a 10 GB text file? Why do you want to transfer it using your own protocol? Why do you read the entire file in an array in memory? Why do you use an integer for the size? Solve one or more of these problems, and your problem goes away. Also, read [ask] and elaborate on "cannot handle"; what is the actual error you get, and what have you tried to research?

Comment: What kind of system are you saving the data on? If it's a 32bit windows system you might be running into the 2gb heap memory limitation.

Comment: Also, consider compressing the file

Comment: I would split such large datasets into smaller chunks and reassemble on the receiving side. This could make it easier to do thinks like showing progress, handle failures etc.